# How to pass object id as a parameter to URL

Tags: api, lightning-web-components

I have an api that passes the following parameters like this:

```
https://system_api.php?token={token}&sys={**GET SYSTEM ID FROM SF**}&type=keys">
```

The system id is a field of the Customer System Object.

I'm new to Salesforce and I'm using a lightning web component, but I am having trouble understanding what I need to do to get this field populated as it changes based on Customer System.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the URN in JavaScript and before use it in HTML. But if you want to do a redirection or navigate to some site you can use [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url)